# CakePHP run on another port

Tags: cakephp

I install CakePHP. Let say that I want to run CakePHP on port 8080, instead of port 8765. How can I do that?

I tried to use `bin/cake server 8080`, but with no success. **EDIT - It's just running still on 8765, without saying errors.**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't that an Apache thing?

Comment: It is. CakePHP is an MVC technology for PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use the help

All commands come with help:

```
-> bin/cake server --help

Welcome to CakePHP v3.x.x Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /var/www/example.dev/src/
DocumentRoot: /var/www/example.dev/webroot/
---------------------------------------------------------------
PHP Built-in Server for CakePHP
[WARN] Don't use this at the production environment

Usage:
cake server [-h] [-v] [-q] [-H] [-p] [-d]

Options:

--help, -h           Display this help.
--verbose, -v        Enable verbose output.
--quiet, -q          Enable quiet output.
--host, -H           ServerHost
--port, -p           ListenPort
--document_root, -d  DocumentRoot
```

The port is an option. I.e. the command you are looking for is:

```
-> bin/cake server --port=8080

Welcome to CakePHP v3.x.x Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /var/www/example.dev/src/
DocumentRoot: /var/www/example.dev/webroot
---------------------------------------------------------------
built-in server is running in http://localhost:8080/
You can exit with `CTRL-C`
```